# How many kinds of giants in Norse mythology?

Tags: norse, european-folklore, giants

Besides Frost and Fire Giants, what are the other types of giants?

According to Skjalden.com, there are also Sea Giants, Storm Giants, Mountain Giants
https://skjalden.com/lesser-known-giants-in-norse-mythology/
https://skjalden.com/aurboda/

Comment: I don't have a more knowledgeable answer for this yet, but I think [just those two](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-types-of-Jotun-in-Norse-mythology), if these Quora answers are to be believed.

Comment: @cmw what does he mean when he said "Jotnar could be roughly divided into earthly elements like storm Jotnar, earth Jotnar, mountain Jotnar etc.,"?

Comment: His comparison to pantheons leads me to conclude that he's referring to domains that the jötnar are associated with, similar to how Zeus is associated with storms, Poseidon with the sea, etc. I'm not sure that's accurate, but I don't know yet.

Comment: Wouldnt that make storm/sea giants a classification since Frost Giants are associated with ice and Fire Giants associated with fire?

Comment: I guess the idea is could frost giants also be associated with the sea or fire giants also with storms? As I said, this isn't my area of expertise, but I have a few books I'm looking at that may provide an answer. Also, keep in mind that mythologies are never perfectly logical, so expecting some sort of logical, coherent principle that always works is wrongheaded.

Comment: If a fire giant was associated with storms then I don't think that would make them a fire giant anymore?